# Register and login from Android app using devise gem

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, devise

Since using tokens in devise is no longer possible, what is the way to manage registering/logging from an Android app?

Comment: Already solved. When connecting devise and Android, you have almost nothing to do. Only thing is to keep and use session cookie.

Comment: can you please post an answer or explain it please . thanks

Comment: Does.session cookies exist in android ? Isnt it a feature.of web browsers?